# Multiple Limit / Order By clauses in single Neo4jClient Cypher Call

Tags: neo4jclient

I am trying to call this query

```
queryItem = GraphClientInstance()
                 .Cypher
                 .Start(...)
                 .Match(...)
                 .Where(...)
                 .With(...)
                 .OrderByDescending(..)
                 .Limit(1)
                 .Match(...)
                 .Where(...)
                 .Return(...)
                 .OrderByDescending(..)
                 .Limit(..)
                 .Results;
```

I know this looks kind of long but this is only way I could get it done. Although Cypher allows it but Neo4jClient does not allow me to add multiple Order By or Limit Clauses. I can break it up but then it will be two server calls. Anyway I can make it in one call with Neo4jClient?

Comment: Which version of Neo4jClient?

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: The version is. 1.0.0.590. The error I get on first .OrderByDescending - 'Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah, that's because `With` only returns `ICypherFluentQuery` and not `ICypherFluentQueryReturned<T>`. Hmm. I'll need to get creative. Please raise an issue on the project site.

Comment: Done Issue #140. Hopefully one day I get enough C# understanding to contribute to the project and fix some bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in 1.0.0.593 and above, released on 4th Sep 2013.